# Is the product of exponents of normal iid variables a martingale?

Tags: probability, martingales

I am told that $X_1,\:X_2,\:,\dots$ is a sequence of i.i.d random variables, where $X_i\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ for $i=1,2,\dots$

and that $Y_N=e^{X_1}e^{X_2}\dots e^{X_N}$.

Is $Y_N$ a martingale?

Comment: For some value of $\mu$. What have you tried?

Comment: Any values of $\mu$ and $\sigma$. I think I know how to show that $Y_N$ is integrable, but I am not sure. As for the rest, I am clueless...

Comment: Sorry, I was inaccurate. My take on this is that since $E(Y_N)$ is not constant, $Y_N$ is not a martingale. i.e., $E(Y_N)=\exp^{N(\mu+\sigma^2/2)$ depend on $N$. Is that even close?

Comment: @icaspi Yeah, that's a good idea.